# Is there a better way to do Insertion Sort?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, memcpy, insertion-sort

YouTube Video to Insertion Sort - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU767SDMDvA

This is my implementation of it in C

```
void insertionSort(void *data, uint32_t length, int8_t compareTo(const void * const, const 
  void * const), const size_t bytes){
  uint32_t i;
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    uint8_t isSorted;
    int32_t j;
    isSorted = 0;
    for(j = i - 1; j > -1 && !isSorted; j--){
        isSorted = 1;
        if(compareTo((int8_t *)data + j * bytes, (int8_t *)data + (j + 1) * bytes) > 0){
            uint32_t byteIndex;
            void *valCopy;
            valCopy = malloc(bytes);
            memcpy(valCopy, (int8_t *)data + j * bytes, bytes);

            for(byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bytes; byteIndex++){
                *((int8_t *)data + (j * bytes + byteIndex)) = *((int8_t *)data + ((j + 1) * bytes + byteIndex));
                *((int8_t *)data + ((j + 1) * bytes + byteIndex)) = *((int8_t *)valCopy + byteIndex);
            }

            /**
            instead of the for loop you can replace it with this to make it look more clean
            memcpy((int8_t *)data + j * bytes, (int8_t *)data + (j + 1) * bytes, bytes);
            memcpy((int8_t *)data + (j + 1) * bytes, valCopy, bytes);
            **/

            free(valCopy);
            isSorted = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}


int8_t compareTo(const void * const val1, const void * const val2){
   if(*(const int32_t * const)val1 > *(const int32_t * const)val2)return 1;
   else if(*(const int32_t * const)val1 < *(const int32_t * const)val2)return -1;
   return 0;
}

int main(void){
   int32_t i;
   int32_t data[] = {2, 6, 5, 3, 8, 7, 1, 0};
   int32_t dataLength = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data);

   insertionSort(data, dataLength, &compareTo, sizeof(int32_t));

   for(i = 0; i < dataLength; i++){
       printf("%d ", data[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I was wonder if there is a more efficient way then to copy the value each time using memcpy or the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another answer already observes, calling `malloc()` and `free()` for every swap is unneeded.  All those extra calls indeed appear to be the largest source of inefficiency.  You need at most one `malloc` and one `free` call, but you can get away without *any* for item sizes no larger than a limit you choose.  For example,

```
#define SMALL_ITEM_LIMIT 1024 /* for example */

// ...

void insertionSort(void *data, uint32_t length,
    int8_t compareTo(const void * const, const void * const), const size_t bytes) {
    char auto_buffer[SMALL_ITEM_LIMIT];
    char *temp;

    if (bytes > SMALL_ITEM_LIMIT) {
        temp = malloc(bytes);
        if (temp == NULL) {
            // ... handle allocation failure ...
        }
    } else {
        temp = auto_buffer;
    }

    // ... main part of the sort ...

    if (temp != auto_buffer) {
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

As a minor matter, the use of variable `isSorted` is unnecessary and a bit clumsy.  You can avoid it and probably shave a few cycles by simply `break`ing from the `j` loop when the current element reaches its insertion position.

You ask:

> I was wonder if there is a more efficient way then to copy the value
> each time using memcpy or the for loop?

For a generic sort such as this, where you do not know the type of the items being sorted, there is no alternative to bulk memory operations for moving elements.  I would be inclined to start with `memcpy()` and / or `memmove()`, as it's clearer.  Do not use an inner loop for that without testing on a variety of cases to determine whether it genuinely provides any improvement.

However, you don't necessarily need to move elements one position at a time.  Instead, on each outer-loop iteration, you can locate the insertion position without moving anything, then perform the insertion via a single *n*-element rotation.  For random data, that will tend to perform fewer reads and writes.  That variation might look like this (some names have been changed to make them clearer):

```
void insertionSort(void *data, uint32_t item_count,
        int compare(const void *, const void *), size_t item_size) {
    char auto_buffer[SMALL_ITEM_LIMIT];
    char *temp = (item_size > SMALL_ITEM_LIMIT) ? malloc(item_size) : auto_buffer;

    if (temp) {
        char *char_data = data;  // for clarity; avoids having to cast all the time

        for (uint32_t i = 1; i < count; i++) { // no point in starting at 0
            // Find the insertion position
            for (uint32_t j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                if (compare(char_data +  j      * item_size,
                            char_data + (j - 1) * item_size) >= 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Rotate the current item into position
            if (j != i) {
                memcpy(temp, char_data + i * item_size, item_size);
                memmove(char_data +  j      * item_size,
                        char_data + (j + 1) * item_size,
                        (i - j) * item_size);
                memcpy(char_data + j * item_size, temp, item_size);
            }
        }

        if (temp != auto_buffer) {
            free(temp);
        }
    } // else memory allocation failed
}
```

Alternatively, it might be a bit more efficient in practice to implement the rotations more in parallel with the comparisons to take better advantage of cache and data locality.  This like performing only half (or maybe one third) of a swap for each exchange.  The sort loop for that would be something like this:

```
        for (uint32_t i = 1; i < count; i++) { // no point in starting at 0
            // store element i
            memcpy(temp, char_data + i * item_size, item_size);

            // Find the insertion position
            for (uint32_t j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                if (compare(char_data +  j      * item_size,
                            char_data + (j - 1) * item_size) < 0) {
                    // shift element j - 1 up one position
                    memcpy(char_data + (j - 1) * item_size,
                           char_data +  j      * item_size,
                           item_size);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (j != i) {
                // Put the erstwhile value of element i into its position
                memcpy(char_data + j * item_size, temp, item_size);
            }
        }
```

Which of those will actually perform better in practice under any particular circumstances is a question to answer by testing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `static char auto_buffer[SMALL_ITEM_LIMIT];`? Great answer though.

Comment: No, it wouldn't @PatrickRoberts, because then it would not be thread-safe.  And allocating local variables is effectively free in typical implementations.

Comment: There is another little known optimization. Compare the element with the element at 0. If it is smaller, just rotate the array; no need to call `compare`. Otherwise, compare only values; no need to test for `j > 0`: an element at 0 is a natural sentinel. The number of conditional branches is cut in half.

Comment: Good observation, @user58697.  I find that that makes no appreciable difference on random data, but it has a dramatic effect on the otherwise worst case of reverse-sorted data.

Comment: It is not my observation. Credit goes where credit is due. I learned it from Alex Stepanov, and he said that he learned it from Donald Knuth.

Comment: The greatest difference it makes is when the array is _almost sorted_ (consider a quick sort with the cut-off size).

Answer (score 2):

The most inefficient part of your implementation is the unnecessary calls to `malloc()` and `free()`, which should only need to be called once and then reused for each swap in the algorithm. Here's a possible implementation of that:

```c
void isort(void* ptr, size_t count, size_t size, int (*comp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    bool sorted;
    void* a;
    void* b;
    void* t;

    // don't allocate temporary memory when unneeded
    if (count == 0) return;
    t = malloc(size);

    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        sorted = false;

        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && !sorted; --j)
        {
            sorted = true;
            a = (char*)ptr + size * j;
            b = (char*)ptr + size * (j + 1);

            if (comp(a, b) > 0)
            {
                memcpy(t, a, size);
                memcpy(a, b, size);
                memcpy(b, t, size);
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    free(t);
}
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiIAKykADqmmEltTTv2DX7xTpTcytdW3snWXlA2gYCZmICbz0DThk5TAVPOISCYMsbO0cZeMTk3zTpUryzArCihwBKGVRtYmQOAHIAUgAmAGYzZB0sAGpu/vUq9GtULQA6BAnsboAGAEE%2Bwdph7TGJqYJ8VEXltc2BoZHMccnp1jxrU/6Vja2rvZuDquIzYGfXpsNgA3VB4dCjPDSEgECCg8EAKlGzgIZFG7gAXpgxARRmhtPRSOi8FiccSsUSzLiIAi0LpnI0IGhaFVRvD0AiiczWeyEY1GudugB2ABC51GEvJ2NxeAmYo2kqlZL4cvFktmWnRMMw6FVCslvNGzD160VhusJrNYI5owIJrVEoA9I7Rug6GBOri2KxUCwCDd/fSSAkAJ6jXSYXQkMMAdwQqlGBPMOp1DshVFGTNa9FuABEJrnRqtGqNiJgCG1aJbJbiC%2BHvb6IJjMAL%2BvKgabJTRiJm8Hmi3LIbd1Hjs3a2%2BNemKp3gBfqJcL24rFdDEjr%2B1Q2LJ7fPl93M3x%2B32ALSjTiDw9nfqF1aTgBsfTvozAYFX/t1E%2BPx74c87y/Goppv%2BEpvuudaotomDVsBkrMP2TIIAkfIoj2fQilKoxIiqbZAcB1jwcgiHEMhqKTuhzaYQeZFnq27a4f%2BeAZlm9IQMwRLWCWyxFr%2BMGKou9G8RGujIM4IYQAQRJsVKtECTBQkiWJUnWESzYybuvGSvJokQMptoqSSLbQRpkqgRCdabqw244epwHCvmNkLkK9l/gBzlplQZaYOJambE5gobFSo70mIVJZiyuKGlJ3IRdaSIcYKgG7mWFbELQmFhayVJ8nBp4IhlMr0HyFrWb5bkBTmujMGYcLWr%2B/G7oF6DMPE3QOGKDiFnWi6jL0RJ3kSTijP0RIABxEkKRJpEWrlGc2ZIUXWzaoBmCJNS1JUrgZZL4jmi0GctrrNXBLrNrNW0yjuLlQjCEBrVFY76RSQXOCF9A%2Be5JC9v2qyDn2ByjgS47oWhaGzmm9UuYqzi/PQVAQH0vR9A4Zm9L1h0tW1sodT5fF%2BW8SXlpWA4lXZ5ydM0rAgJ0DidKQBidKstOoFTI7Qm0HSTv0nC0wQVOM/ypAANaOL08wjb0I3cA43B3tLvSrAAnL0E2U503C0/TjOkMznS09IICrKQvMM%2BTpBwLAMCICgqD0ng7BkBQzHOHbRTIMAnCrL1VB2/6xD6zpfO09YZihlT3OkHSEb0AA8rQrAhoHpBYJVojsGHtP4GWWTApg%2Bsm6QmAAB6ZNo/qJ1Scjp0IjzEKGmhYFXqJ4LogfNDQ9BMGwHA8PwgjCKIIASGIUgPNY%2BuQM0qAop4efHtMBbIJw4dRJkMQqGo5SpAXaj5KE4R%2BG4Hh0JvB8BJ4u%2BFPYlQZFkdA5GUWgpIIK%2B37E1QX/UV8lLkJ%2BVO/tR7yKJwZobN2jdwplTGmdNE460LiNO8x47zcFGMAZAyAzyrHmL0TMuBCCfS2FNTQtt7ac2AaMdQPNW7NGFtwIU8xOBCk4NLBw/QpZCgVqsIUvBVbq1IC3BwhtNZMypnrA2RtW5m0thAJArQCDOFLuQSgdJnb20MPgIgX926MBYGnHuMZa7OHThA6mGsYFUwIaMGMhAECjDgQgpBKC0EYKwZQk2At4zMCwPYCAxjeH8MEWY3WMgxHG35tQkAtD6GMOYawhw7DOHcKpv0Ux%2BcdauLCUIKmvQUlazSeItxzQc5%2B08BEoAA%3D%3D)

Answer (score -2):

Insertion sort is not appropriate to use on arrays, due to having to perform the costly re-arrangement of the array.  Insertion sort should be used on linkedLists.  On arrays, a similar but better algo is selection sort.  Of course divide and conquer algos such as quicksort or merge sort are also good.

Comment: Use merge sort on linked lists.  For linked lists, merge sort is simple, requires no additional memory (or at most, log(n) stack memory, depending on how you do it), and is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: While recommending not to use insertion sort on arrays is good advice in general, it misses the point of this question which invites critique on the implementation of insertion sort, not on the algorithm chosen for the exercise.

Comment: Almost every sorting algorithm rearranges the elements being sorted (Counting Sort is an exception, but it's inapplicable to many types of data).  In some -- but not all -- cases, the rearrangements can be cheaper on a linked list than on an array, but that's irrelevant if it's an array that you need to sort.  And it does not itself strongly distinguish different algorithms.  Insertion sort is a fine choice for arrays -- on average, among the best of the comparison sorts for arrays and linked lists alike.  Not that any of this actually addresses the question posed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Insertion sort and selection sort have identical comparison performance (n^2), but selection sort doesn't need to shuffle the data so requires less swaps (n swaps as opposed to n^2 swaps).  For arrays, insertion sort is inferior to selection sort as well as divide and conquer strategies (n log n).  It's fine for linked lists since swaps doesn't need reshuffles, but there's no reason to use it on arrays - period.

Comment: @John, the two have comparison counts with the same asymptotic scaling, but Insertion Sort performs half as many comparisons in the average case as Selection Sort.  Furthermore, there is at least one read associated with each comparison, and in the Insertion case there is a write associated with each.  Supposing that reads and writes cost the same, the reduction in reads associated with comparisons pays for the extra writes in the Insertion case, but Selection Sort still has its swaps to pay for on top, and extra comparisons.

Comment: If writes are more expensive than reads then yes, Selection Sort is a better choice, but that's not the usual case.  Moreover, although Insertion Sort has somewhat worse worst-case performance, it has far better best-case performance, and it benefits from the kinds of partial order that often appear in real-world data.  In practice, Insertion Sort is the better bet, and generally the *best* bet among comparison sorts.  Of course divide-and-conquer sorts beat it for large enough inputs, but Insertion's low overhead relative to these gives it the edge even over them for small ones.

Comment: @John, you inspired me to approach the question from an empirical perspective, which in turn led to this CodeReview question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248340/131879.  The bottom line is that operating on randomly-ordered arrays, using commodity hardware and operating systems, my pretty-good Insertion Sort *beats the pants off* my comparably-good Selection Sort in practice.  I find that Insertion beats Selection even in the former's worst case, even without applying a known optimization to the Insertion sort that greatly improves its performance in such cases.